# Ejecutar script al cargar la página con una opción de select seleccionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script que funciona bien, lo tengo para un formulario de registro.

Cuando selecciono una opción me carga de datos el otro select, pero para editar el registro, ya el select viene seleccionado, pero no carga el otro select dependiente, sé que se debe a que tengo el script con el método `.change`, pero no sé como solucionar que al cargar la página para editar (que ya está seleccionada la opción) me liste el select dependiente (Me carguen los datos correspondientes a la opción seleccionada).

Mi script

```
$("#user_id").change(event=>{
  $.get("/vehicles/"+event.target.value+"", function(response,province){
      $("#vehicle_id").empty();
      for(i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
          $("#vehicle_id").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].brand+ " " +response[i].model+" </option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con un [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) después de la carga de la página a editar:

```
$('#user_id').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Definitivamente lo más sencillo suele ser mejor. Estaba creando una respuesta sugiriendo crear una función y otros líos, pero la solución es muy simple. Excelente respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, espero que funcione :-)  No se si sabrá implamentarla en su código aún

Comment: Mucgas gracias, me funcionó muy bien. Gracias!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si te ha sido útil para que no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias.

Comment: Sí, ya lo hago. Gracias a tí!